# Lucid works enterprise

Tags: sql-server, solr, lucene

I am using lucid works enterprise search server and I want to import data from database but it seems it has problem with reading data from database. I use jdbc4 from microsoft and the server gives the following error:

Could not create jdbc connection. Please recheck driver, URL, username and password. Database exception: The TCP/IP connection to the host 127.0.0.1/Vasael, port 1433 has failed. Error: "null. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".

Dose anybody have a solution for that?

thanks

Comment: Lucidworks enterprise being a commercial application, maybe you should call the support?